# Python numpy boolean masking on 2d np array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2d numpy arrays X and Y that look like:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[4,3,2,1],[7,8,9,0]]
            )
Y = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,2,4],[1,1,1], [0,0,0]]
            )
```

I want to remove all the arrays in Y that are all 0's (i.e. np.zeros), and all the corresponding arrays at the same index in the X array.

So, for these two X,Y arrays, I'd like back:

```
X = np.array([[4,5,6,7],[4,3,2,1]]
            )
Y = np.array([[1,2,4],[1,1,1]]
            )
```

X and Y will always have the same length, and X and Y will always be rectangular (i.e. every array within X will have the same length, and every array within Y will have the same length).

I tried using a loop but that doesn't seem to be as effective for large X and Y

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean array indicating any non zero element for each row and then filter with [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
any_zero = (Y != 0).any(1)

X[any_zero]
#[[4 5 6 7]
# [4 3 2 1]]

Y[any_zero]    
#[[1 2 4]
# [1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to get a mask of which rows of Y are all zeros.
This can be done with the any method and setting the axis to 1

```
Y.any(axis = 1)
```

Will return `array([False,  True,  True, False])`
You can use this array to get which rows you want to return from X and Y

```
X[Y.any(axis = 1)]
```

will return

```
array([[4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

and

```
Y[Y.any(axis = 1)]
```

will return

```
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```